# Как заморозить переменную в Java?

Tags: java, объекты

Есть вес кошки, есть максимальный и минимальный возможный вес, при выходе за пределы допустимого веса кошка умирает. Как заморозить переменную "weight", т.е. что-бы вес мёртвой кошки нельзя было менять?

Я попытался использовать final, но по моему он работает только при объявлении новой переменной. Или не надо было писать условие if в конструкторе, хотя при написании в классе всё становится ещё хуже...

```
public Cat()
{
    weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
    originWeight = weight;
    minWeight = 1000.0;
    maxWeight = 9000.0;
    count++;
    if(weight < minWeight || weight > maxWeight) {
        this.weight = final();
    }
}
```

> Хм, а чем плох сеттер с проверкой? ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setter#Java

Что-то такое уже есть. Но не понимаю как зафиксировать вес?

```
public String getStatus()
{
    if(weight < minWeight) {
        count--;
        return "Dead";
    }
    else if(weight > maxWeight) {
        count--;
        return "Exploded";
    }
    else if(weight > originWeight) {
        return "Sleeping";
    }
    else {
        return "Playing";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже [писали в коментах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864749/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-java#comment1397655_864749), Вам нужно сделать `setter` с условием.

```
class Cat {
    private int weight = 0;

    public Cat(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        // Если вес меньше 100 изменяем значение переменной иначе ничего не делаем
        // Если условие не выполнено можно выкинуть ошибку или еще что то сделать
        if (this.weight < 100){
            this.weight = weight;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Кот слишком толстый");
        }
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Cat {
    public static int count;

    private double weight;
    private boolean isDead;

    public Cat(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.count++;

        if (weightKill()) {
            System.out.println('Dead before born');
        }
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        if (this.isDead) {
            System.out.println('This cat is dead yet');

            return;
        } 

        this.weight = weight;

        if (weightKill()) {
            System.out.println('This diet is killing');
        }
    }

    private boolean weightKill() {
        if (this.weight > 20.0 || this.weight < 1.0) {
            this.isDead = true;
            this.count--;
        }

        return this.isDead;
    }
}
```